# Bloch's theorem and Bloch's state

Tags: condensed-matter, berry-pancharatnam-phase, crystals

The question is not so much about the theorem, but more about what it means in this context: [see this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_connection_and_curvature#Applications_in_crystals).

So yes, because of Bloch's theorem the Hamiltonian eigenstates in a crystalline system can be written as
\begin{align}
\psi_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r})=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r}),
\end{align}
and so the Berry connection can be defined:
\begin{align}
A_{n}(\vec{k})=i\langle n(\vec{k})|\nabla_{\vec{k}}|n(\vec{k})\rangle,
\end{align}
but what in the world is $|n(\vec{k})\rangle$?

I've read a few articles on topological insulators and they always seem to start off with the Bloch wavefunction $e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} u_k(\vec{r})$, and then somehow they magically get the ket $|u(\vec{k})\rangle$ from which the Berry connection is defined... is $|u(\vec{k})\rangle$ the column vector comprised of the Fourier coefficients of $u_\vec{k}(\vec{r})$ w.r.t. $e^{i\vec{G}\cdot\vec{r}}$ or what?

Comment: As the article says, $n$ is the band index. If you were to represent the ket $|u_{n}(\mathbf{k})\rangle$ in a basis (in this case the basis of a Hilbert space spanned by bands) then you could write it as a column vector where each component corresponds to the Bloch wavefunction for each band (labeled by $n$). Note: for a the simplest topological insulator model you need at least two bands: valence and conduction band. In that case you'll have a $2 \times 1$ column vector.

Comment: @NanoPhys How do you get rid of the position $\vec{r}$ dependence then? Is that absorbed in the way the inner product is defined? But $|n(\vec{k})\rangle$ should exist on its own, and should be independent of $\vec{r}$. How does one get it from $u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r})$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The $\mathbf{r}$ does indeed get absorbed in the definition of the inner product. Note that a Bloch state is uniquely labeled by $n$ and $\mathbf{k}$ independent of what basis it is represented in. In your case, you are writing down the Bloch "wavefunction" $\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\propto e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}u_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ in the position basis. The inner product $\langle u_{n}(\mathbf{k})|\dots|u_{n}(\mathbf{k})\rangle$ has to be basis independent.

Comment: @NanoPhys So what would Bloch's theorem be, without going into any explicit basis (in particular, the position basis)? What I mean is, what can we say about the abstract kets $|\psi\rangle$? See http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5693 , eqn 27-30. I'm not sure why that is true unless he's already assuming that the kets are already in the position basis

Comment: Equation (28) is valid. The $e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$ is simply a phase factor; two kets can, in general, be related in that fashion. To make better sense of it, take a $\langle\mathbf{r}|$ on both sides. You'll get $\langle\mathbf{r}|\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}\rangle = e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot\mathbf{r}} \langle \mathbf{r}|u_{n\mathbf{k}}\rangle\Rightarrow\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}u_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$, which is our familiar Bloch wavefunction

Answer (score 1):

I have discussed this question with my friend, and he gives a satisfying answer:
the Bloch state is $|\psi_k\rangle$, then we define a new state $|u_k\rangle$ by :
$|u_k\rangle=e^{-ik\cdot\hat{r}}|\psi_k\rangle$. Notice that $\hat{r}$ in phase factor is the **position operator**, not a parameter in real space. You can use this definition and the Bloch theorem: $T(R)|\psi_k\rangle=e^{ik\cdot R}|\psi_k\rangle$ (where $T(R)=e^{i\frac{\hat{p}\cdot R}{\hbar}}$, $p$ is the momentum operator) to check the wavefunction of $|u_k\rangle$ is periodic.

The way to understand the definition is that: $e^{-ik\cdot\hat{r}}$ is a translation operator in momentum space, so if we use the wavefunction in momentum space, we will get :$u_k(k')=\psi_k(k'+k)$.

But one important thing to remember: $|u_k\rangle$ is not the eigenstate of the origional Hamiltonian $H$, but it's the eigenstate of the modified Hamiltonian: $H(k)=e^{-ik\hat\cdot{r}}He^{ik\cdot\hat{r}}$. When we talk about the band theory, we usually talk about Hamiltonian $H(k)$ and states $|u_k\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

First recall that when talking about Berry phases we are working in the adiabatic approximation where the Hamiltonian is allowed to be controlled by some slow varying variables, which in this case are $\vec{k}(t)$. In this case the underlying assumption is that all of the time dependence is encapsulated in these variables $H(\vec{r}, \vec{p}, \vec{k}(t))$.

$|n(\vec{k})\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian which are allowed to depend on $\vec{k}$ since we are working in the adiabatic approximation. Recall now that in the Berry phases we look at accumulated phase from a cyclic process $\gamma(0) = \gamma(T)$, and assume w.l.o.g that we start with the eigenstate $n(\vec{k})$ which will not change under the adiabatic approximation. In this case the connection is given by the infinitesmal change of the state due to changes in $k$
\begin{equation}
i A_n(\vec{k}) = \langle n(\vec{k}) | \nabla_k | n(\vec{k})\rangle
\end{equation}